# How can I add a 2" shower drain into this toilet plumbed configuration?

Tags: drain-waste-vent

This type of drain configuration works well in my situation, but I have a 2" shower drain I need to add to this and share the vent.

Where and how can I do that? Wye on the horizontal trap arm? Sanitary tee on the vertical?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

U could t into the 2" vertically as long as your 6" above flood level rim. But I'm not sure where your main vent stack is  . U need a full size vent stack going out roof.

Comment: Hi! Would you mind [edit]ing your post to use full words, please. It gives your answer much more credibility.